# How to filter the table contents and export the results to csv using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to get the selected column values of a table of a web page using powershell.. My code is

```
 $url1 = "D:\MyPowershell\Html.html"
 $ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url1);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep 10; 
    # $ie.refresh();

} 

$a = Get-Content "D:\MyPowershell\Html.html"

 $x=($ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr"))`
  | where {
  ($_.innerText -match "2 - High") -and
  $_.innerText -notmatch "Work in Progress" }`
| % {
  $number, $priority, $state= $_.children | select -Expand innerText
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'Number' = $number
    'Priority' = $priority
    'State'   = $state

  }
} | select Number, Priority|Export-csv 'D:\Html.csv' -NoType -Delimiter "`t"
```

It is a web page created by me. There are no other tables The HTML code of the web page is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th name="number"> Number</th>
<th name="priority">Priority</th>
<th name="state">State</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td name="check_task" class="list_checkbox ">INC0811168</td>
<td class="vt" title="" style="background-color:orange">2 - High</td>
<td style="" class="vt" title="">Assigned</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td name="check_task" class="list_checkbox ">INC081rr68</td>
<td class="vt" title="">0 - None</td>
<td style="" class="vt" title="">Work in Progress</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

With this edited code I am getting no errors but the values are not displayed in the csv and only the 'Html' file is being created.Instead I am getting some encoded text in notepad. Here INC0811168, '2 -High' and 'Assigned'  are separate fields.. I need to get the data with space between the separate column values.  I need to filter the data and need to get only 'INC****' and '2-High' columns.. The retrieved data is exported to csv. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the inner text of the row mangles the individual fields into a single string. Use something like this instead:

```
$ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr") | where {
  $_.innerText -match "2 - High" -and
  $_.innerText -notmatch "Work in Progress"
} | % {
  $id, $priority, $status, $summary = $_.children | select -Expand innerText
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'ID'       = $id
    'Priority' = $priority
    'Status'   = $status
    'Summary'  = $summary
  }
} | select ID, Priority | Export-Csv 'D:\Html.csv' -NoType -Delimiter "`t"
```

Replace `` `t `` (tabulator) with whatever delimiter you want the CSV to use.

Comment: I am getting error `Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "o
bj" to a non-null value`. I have given the name of the <th> values of the table for $id,$priority etc.. Still not working

Comment: @user3750784 What do you mean by "given the name of the <th> values of the table for $id,$priority etc."? Please update your question with the code you currently have and also provide sample input data, so people here can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited in my code and provided the html code of the table heading and table data of the web page..

Comment: @user3750784 Do you see `-or($ie.document.getElementsByTagName("th"))` anywhere in my code sample? If not: why did you add this? Please refrain from making modifications of your own. The term `(expression) -or (expression)` makes the result a boolean value, so there are no rows to process in the pipeline. Also, your HTML sample is incomplete as there are no `<tr>` and `<table>` tags. Please provide a complete table structure.

Comment: When I used ($ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr") alone i get the error `Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.`

Comment: @user3750784 I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the information you provided. Please update your question with the exact code that causes the error, including instantiation of the InternetExplorer object and loading of the page. You may obfuscate the actual URL. Were you able to isolate which of the 2 `select` statements causes the error? Is there just one table in the HTML page, or are there more?

Comment: how could i change my code if it is the third table of the web page